# How can I get file found by find command to current dir?

Tags: bash, shell, find

I have tried this command:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo find /tmp -name *file.doc* -exec 'mv "{}" ./file.docx' '{}' \;
```

but error:

```
find: mv "a b cfile.docx" ./file.docx: No such file or directory'
```

But the mv command looks just as it should (first arg - quoted file found in `/tmp` dir, second arg - new name for that file in current directory - that is `mv SOURCE DEST` is correct). If I do it in the `/tmp` dir - it would work, so why the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find is trying to execute the file `'mv "a b cfile.docx" ./file.docx'` but there's no such file.

This is what is happening:

```
$ 'mv "a b cfile.docx" ./file.docx'
-bash: mv "a b cfile.docx" ./file.docx: No such file or directory
```

bash also is not able to find the file we've asked it to execute.

The intention is to execute `mv`. Try this fixed version.

- I've removed the single quote surrounding the arg to `-exec`
- also the `{}` in the end is not needed. we just need the file substituted in one place

```
sudo find /tmp -name *file.doc* -exec mv "{}" ./file.docx \;
```